# Fuzzy Clustering Evaluation Metrics

Tags: clustering, fuzzy, model-evaluation

I have a corpus of text documents which I am clustering using LDA & C-Means. I am trying to find the best input for the LDA algorithm (stemming, stop words removed etc), and I want to evaluate the results of the C-Means based on these different inputs.

What are the recommended fuzzy clustering evaluation metrics? I have done a fair bit of reading and there doesn't appear to be a strong consensus. ACI seems to be somewhat regularly mentioned - but not enough to convince me it is definitely what I am after.

Any advice would be helpful,

Also - I am currently programming in Python, so if there is an implementation of a method that would also be useful to know about. 
(I am also having success importing to R)

Comment: Hi, @SamPassmore I have recently encountered with the same problem? Have you solved it already?

Comment: @maple - No I haven't unfortunately. My 'solution' currently is to treat each cluster individually, decide what Topic is represented in the cluster, then use the resulting binary variable to calculate how pure the cluster is (ie. how much noise is in the cluster after deciding on what topic it is) and calculating what percentage of the topic is captured by the cluster (ie. how many of the assigned topics are caught in the cluster and how many are not)